# BGE Switching camera

Tags: game-engine

I have 3 cameras in my game scene. When I press <kbd>P</kbd>, I am using one camera. How can I use the other cameras?

Like pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to front view, almost like a racing car game's camera views, which have a lot of view options for the player. I don't mean split screen .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the active camera with the Scene actuator, which has a "Set Camera" mode.